# Как вызвать родительский метод в C# (override) через Reflection?

Tags: c#, winforms, рефлексия

Переопределив protected-метод класса Button в C#, я могу вызвать его родительский метод:

```
base.OnPaint(e);
```

Однако, в связи с сутью проекта я не имею прямого доступа к base, и обратиться к родительскому методу можно только извне, и через рефлексию (System.Reflection). Вызываю:

```
typeof(Button).GetMethod("OnPaint", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(obj, e);
```

Однако вместо ожидаемого поведения выполняется тот код, который и был установлен мной. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такой вопрос уже задавался на английском Stack Overflow: [Use reflection to invoke an overridden base method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357729/use-reflection-to-invoke-an-overridden-base-method). Рекомендую изучить ответы там.

Для реализации можно использовать [`RuntimeMethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtimemethodhandle.getfunctionpointer?view=netcore-3.1#System_RuntimeMethodHandle_GetFunctionPointer) для создания делегата, ссылающегося на родительский метод:

```
//получаем метод
var method = typeof(Button).GetMethod("OnPaint", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
//указатель на метод
var pointer = method.MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer();
//создаем из указателя делегат
var action = (Action<PaintEventArgs>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Action<PaintEventArgs>), obj, pointer);
//вызываем делегат
action(e);
```

Если имеется возможность редактировать код класса-наследника, то возможно будет проще добавить отдельный метод для доступа к реализации предка. В этом случае не понадобится рефлексия вообще:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}

/// <summary>
/// Второй метод для обращения к base.OnPaint
/// </summary>
public void OnBasePaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
     base.OnPaint(e);
}
```